# Failure method of validation in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the validation plugin in which we validate whole form using validate plugin of jquery http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

By this we can setup **what to call  when validation of form is correct like**

```
$('#frmForgetPassword')
.validate(
{
    submitHandler : function(form) {
        alert('true');
        }
}
```

this **submitHandler()** is fired when **form is validated in correct sense** but i want to fire this action when form is incorrectly filled.
where to right code for that **event**

Comment: may be this [**link**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules) would help. click the examples tab

Answer (score 0):

you can rather call valid() method of jquery.validation plugin which return boolean value for example

```
$("#myform").validate();
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
   alert($("#myform").valid());
  //Here you can check if valid() method is true proceed or else you can return false;
  if($("#myform").valid())
 {
  // your task
  }
else
{
 return false;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `invalidHandler`

[As stated in the docs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#invalidhandler), this is a "callback for custom code when an invalid form is submitted."